# Open named pipe for writing and use it in select()

Tags: linux, select, named-pipes, nonblocking, fifo

My overall goal is to pass report information into a named pipe if (and only if) there is a reader connected to that named pipe.  If there is no reader, I want to avoid building the report information etc.  Since this is happening in a scenario where other data streams are handled via `select()`, I want to add the named pipe to the streams which are "ready for writing".

So, I want to open a named pipe for writing and need to give it to `select()` in a way so that `select()` only returns in case there really is a reader on the other end of the named pipe.

Normally, if there is no reader, the `open` call already hangs; unfortunately, I cannot give an `open` action to `select()`—only open file descriptors are valid.

To get a decent file descriptor, I'm currently creating a dummy reader (I open the named pipe for reading myself), then open it for writing, and then close the dummy reader again:

```
dummy = os.open(fifoPath, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
# ^^^ without the NONBLOCK, this will hang until another process is ready to write
fifo = os.open(fifoPath os.O_WRONLY)
os.close(dummy)
```

If I now open another reader, he will receive what I write into the named pipe, so this aspect is working.

But now `select()` always returns the `fifo` as ready-to-write, even if there is no reader connected:

```
r, w, e = select.select([], [ fifo ], [])
print w[0]
```

This will always and at once print the `fifo` value.

And writing into the named pipe also does not hang, no matter how much I write:

```
fifo.write('foo')
```

The data I write just is lost as no reader is connected.

When opening my dummy reader, I am passing the flag `O_NONBLOCK` because otherwise this opening hangs as well.  I tried various methods but could not figure out how to do this properly.

Can anybody tell me how to combine writing into named pipes with `select()`?

(The code above is in Python but I guess the problem is not really connected to Python but rather a Linux/Unix problem, so I won't tag this question as Python.)

Answer (score 2):

See `man 7 fifo` WRT how the pipe should work non-block.

> A process can open a FIFO in nonblocking mode.  In this case, opening for read-only will succeed even if no-one has opened on the write side yet, opening for write-only will  fail  with  ENXIO  (no  such device or address) unless the other end has already been opened.
>
> Under  Linux,  opening  a FIFO for read and write will succeed both in blocking and nonblocking mode. **This can be used to open a FIFO for writing while there are no readers  available.**   A  process  that  uses both ends of the connection in order to communicate with itself should be very careful to avoid deadlocks.

That should get you around the `dummy` hack.  Using the fd with `select()`, however, is I think a non-starter.  You could instead use a  short timeout with `select()` to facilitate polling the fd with `write()` at intervals inside your main loop, exploiting the fact that...

> When a process tries to write to a FIFO that is not opened for read on the other side, the process is sent a SIGPIPE signal.

...by setting a global to `true` before the call and `false` inside a SIGPIPE handler to indicate there's no reader.

Python may be an issue here, though, since you should be getting this signal already but apparently are not. It could be because of the `dummy` hack (you really have to get rid of that).

Another, perhaps better idea, is to fork a handler for the fifo that uses blocking calls, but also maintains a normal pair (read/write) of pipe descriptors to the main process.  One of those (the writer; i.e., read by the main process) can be used with `select()`.  The fork waits on `open()` and signals main when a reader connects.

Beware that once you reach EOF because the reader disconnected, *you must re-open the pipe*.  Do not continue to use the same fd.

If at all feasible I'd opt for a [unix local socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_socket) over a fifo.

Comment: 1. I'm polling right now and try to avoid that (so proposing that is in the wrong direction ;-).  2. Opening a file for read/writing is non-blocking because it means that there is a reader and a writer, so neither operation blocks; but effectively this means that `select()` will never block (as I want it to); so probably this is the same situation I'm currently in.  3. Using threads/processes might be a solution, but I would not mix that with `select()`; then I would make a thread for each aspect and use proper synchronization mechanisms.  But I would prefer to stick with `select()` :-/

Comment: Well, of course you can have your cake and eat it too!  We all know that's what programming is all about ;)

Comment: I probably receive no SIGPIPE because none is sent (Python wouldn't swallow that silently).  I guess it only is sent when there is _no_ reader, but my dummy seems to count as an existing reader in that aspect, even if it is closed already :-/   So I conclude that I probably cannot handle writing to a fifo with `select()` :-(  Your answer is very much appreciated!